# How do I display an MS Access Table Attachment or an image stored in a SharePoint location on a form?

Tags: vba, image, ms-access, sharepoint, office365

I am making a small game for a work project using Microsoft Access for Office 365. I have a table with all of the answers and a related pic stored as an attachment. Users will scroll through records supplied via the Record Source via SQL query.

I want to display the image related to each record as the user navigates.

I would prefer to store the images elsewhere, but not all intended users have access to a common network folder. I do have access to common SharePoint location where I can upload their results in a linked SharePoint list, but when I attempt to insert an image from a SharePoint location, MS Access does not allow "web addresses".

In testing, I was using VBA to display the image (hosted on a network folder) as the background via the Picture Property on a sub-form, but because not all users have access to a common network folder, I can't do this in production. (Discovered there was no common folder after I created this.)

How do I display that picture in the attachment?

**OR**

How do I use SharePoint to host the images?

Are either of these things possible with 'out of the box' MS Access?

edit: using .accdr format to prevent users from looking at the answers in the tables

Comment: Review https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/204796/how-to-add-attachment-column-to-a-sharepoint-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you will have URLs to the pictures, you can use my fancy function *UrlContent*:

```vb
' Download (picture) file from a URL of a hyperlink field to a
' (temporary) folder, and return the full path to the downloaded file.
'
' This can be used as the control source for a bound picture control.
' If no Folder is specified, the user's IE cache folder is used.
'
' Typical usage in the RecordSource for a form or report where Id is
' the unique ID and Url is the hyperlink field holding the URL to
' the picture file to be displayed:
'
'   - to a cached file where parameter Id is not used:
'
'   Select *, UrlContent(0, [Url]) As Path From SomeTable;
'
'   - or, where Id is used to create the local file name:
'
'   Select *, UrlContent([Id], [Url], "d:\somefolder") As Path From SomeTable;
'
' Then, set ControlSource of the bound picture control to: Path
'
' 2017-05-28. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function UrlContent( _
    ByVal Id As Long, _
    ByVal Url As String, _
    Optional ByVal Folder As String) _
    As Variant

    Const NoError   As Long = 0
    Const Dot       As String = "."
    Const BackSlash As String = "\"
    
    Dim Address     As String
    Dim Ext         As String
    Dim Path        As String
    Dim Result      As String
    
    ' Strip leading and trailing octothorpes from URL string.
    Address = HyperlinkPart(Url, acAddress)
    ' If Address is a zero-length string, Url was not wrapped in octothorpes.
    If Address = "" Then
        ' Use Url as is.
        Address = Url
    End If
    
    If Folder = "" Then
        ' Import to IE cache.
        Result = DownloadCacheFile(Address)
    Else
        If Right(Folder, 1) <> BackSlash Then
            ' Append a backslash.
            Folder = Folder & BackSlash
        End If
    
        ' Retrieve extension of file name.
        Ext = StrReverse(Split(StrReverse(Address), Dot)(0))
        ' Build full path for downloaded file.
        Path = Folder & CStr(Id) & Dot & Ext
        
        If DownloadFile(Address, Path) = NoError Then
            Result = Path
        End If
    End If
    
    UrlContent = Result
    
End Function
```

Full code, documentation, and a demo can be found in my project [VBA.PictureUrl](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.PictureUrl).

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Are 'DownloadCacheFile' and 'DownloadFile' part of a Reference library I can point to in Access or are these additional functions you developed?

Comment: They are from the module _Internet.bas_ from the linked repository. You can simply include/import the module to your application.

Comment: This was a perfect answer.  Thank you!